# how to read and change the xml file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Thank you very much for reading my question.

and this is my xml file. (for node Songs, many childNodes named Song)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xmlData>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <Songs>
        <Song>
            <artist>mic</artist>
            <track>2</track>
            <column>happy</column>
            <date>14</date>
        </Song>
        <Song>
            <artist>cool</artist>
            <track>2</track>
            <column>work</column>
            <date>4</date>
        </Song>
    </Songs>
</xmlData>
```

reading xml, i use the following code:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlFilePath);

        XmlNode versionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/xmlData/version");
        Console.WriteLine(versionNode.Name + ":\t" + versionNode.InnerText);

        XmlNode SongsNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/xmlData/Songs");
        Console.WriteLine(SongsNode.Name + "\n");

        XmlDocument docSub = new XmlDocument();
        docSub.LoadXml(SongsNode.OuterXml);

        XmlNodeList SongList = docSub.SelectNodes(@"/Songs/Song");

        if (SongList != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode SongNode in SongList)
            {
                XmlNode artistDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("artist");
                Console.WriteLine(artistDetail.Name + "\t: " + artistDetail.InnerText);

                XmlNode trackDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("track");
                Console.WriteLine(trackDetail.Name + "\t: " + trackDetail.InnerText);

                XmlNode columnDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("column");
                Console.WriteLine(columnDetail.Name + "\t: " + columnDetail.InnerText);

                XmlNode dateDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("date");
                Console.WriteLine(dateDetail.Name + "\t: " + dateDetail.InnerText + "\n");

            }
        }
```

it seems working.
but how can i write the change to xml file?
maybe, i will change some childNode in Song, and may delete the whole chindNode by artist keyword.

is it possible such as this function 
bool DeleteSongByArtist(string sArtist);
bool ChangeNodeInSong(string sArtist, string sNodeName, string value);

because the "Reading solution is "XmlDucoment", so it is better if "changing solution" by using "XmlDocument"

but, if you have better idea to read and change the xml file, please give me the sample code... and please don't write a name of solution such as "Ling to xml"...acutally, i do many testes, but failed.

Comment: Or simply doc.Save(newFileName);

Comment: @erlvde: is there some reason you created a brand new XmlDocument halfway thru your code? I've answered assuming this was a mistake (because I can't foresee any useful reason to do so).

Answer (score 3):

**Welcome to Stackoverflow!**

You can change the nodes simply by setting a new `.Value` or in your case `.InnerText`.

#### Sample

```
// change the node
trackDetail.InnerText = "NewValue"
// save the document
doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

#### More Information

- [How To: Modify an Existing Xml File](http://geekswithblogs.net/chrisfalter/archive/2006/03/27/73515.aspx)
- [MSDN - XmlDocument.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if change, i think, must find it first, then set new value to InnerText, but how to save it? such as the "docSub" in sample code of mine, if docSub.Save(), it just save the temporal memroy "docSub", but not "doc". i think, only doc can do the change to the xml file in harddisk. how do you think that?

Comment: @erlvde I dont understand. You can save the file using the `Save` method.

Comment: hmm..really sorry, but i have no idea about "Save". i can read xml by XmlDocument, also, i can change the innertext by set method. for "version" tag, we can change it in "doc"(my code please), but for "song" tag, it is not in "doc" but in "docSub", that's why i confused. if Save, should Save "doc", but change in "docSub".

Comment: Did you tried to save change the docSub and save the doc ? Does it work?

Comment: you mean, change "docSub" then save "doc", the xml will saved in harddisk? sorry, i have no idea about that. i will try it later, and i am on bus now, can't compile code. but one more thing, the "change" not only "change some node's innertext", how to delete a "song", or how to add a "song"? really thank you for your help.

Comment: Please try that later and come back to write another comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an XmlWriter. The easiest way to do it would be something like this...

```
using(XmlWriter writer = new XmlWriter(textWriter))
{
   doc.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Where textWriter is your initialized Text Writer.

Actually, forget that... the easiest way is to call...

```
doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

To delete an artist by artist name add the following method:

```
    bool DeleteSongByArtist(XmlDocument doc, string artistName)
    {
        XmlNodeList SongList = doc.SelectNodes(@"/Songs/Song");
        if (SongList != null)
        {
            for (int i = SongList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (SongList[i]["artist"].InnerText == artistName && SongList[i].ParentNode != null)
                {
                    SongList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(SongList[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

You probably want to clean it up a bit more to be more resilient.  When you call it, change your initial code to be like this.  Don't create the `subDocument` as you want to work with the entire XmlDocument.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(xmlFilePath);

    XmlNode versionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/xmlData/version");
    Console.WriteLine(versionNode.Name + ":\t" + versionNode.InnerText);

    XmlNode SongsNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/xmlData/Songs");
    Console.WriteLine(SongsNode.Name + "\n");

    XmlNodeList SongList = doc.SelectNodes(@"/Songs/Song");

    if (SongList != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode SongNode in SongList)
        {
            XmlNode artistDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("artist");
            Console.WriteLine(artistDetail.Name + "\t: " + artistDetail.InnerText);

            XmlNode trackDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("track");
            Console.WriteLine(trackDetail.Name + "\t: " + trackDetail.InnerText);

            XmlNode columnDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("column");
            Console.WriteLine(columnDetail.Name + "\t: " + columnDetail.InnerText);

            XmlNode dateDetail = SongNode.SelectSingleNode("date");
            Console.WriteLine(dateDetail.Name + "\t: " + dateDetail.InnerText + "\n");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. the xmlWriter..acutally, i tried it before. before we save, we must change "doc" first in my code. so the question is:1: how to change the "doc"? 2: how to assign doc value to xmlwriter?

Comment: For #1) sorry I'll update my code.  For #2) the first example writes a document to the xml writer (the second doesn't need an xmlwriter).

Comment: Updated with your delete question.  You would do a similiar method for changing the text, just instead of deleting the node change whatever Xml you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to save your changes because you made changes to an entirely new document!

You likely meant to do the following:

```
XmlNode SongsNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/xmlData/Songs");
Console.WriteLine(SongsNode.Name + "\n");

// Don't make a new XmlDocument here! Use your existing one
XmlNodeList SongList = SongsNode.SelectNodes(@"/Song");
```

At this point `SongList` is still *living inside* `doc`. Now when you call:

```
doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

Your changes will be saved as you intended.

If you're looking to delete nodes that match certain criteria:

```
// Use XPath to find the matching node
XmlNode song = SongsNode.SelectSingleNode(@"/Song[artist='" + artist + "']");

// Remove it from its Parent
SongsNode.RemoveChild(song);
```

If you're looking to add a new node:

```
// Create the new nodes using doc
XmlNode newSong = doc.CreateElement("Song");

XmlNode artist = doc.CreateElement("artist");
artist.InnerText = "Hello";

// Begin the painstaking process of creation/appending
newSong.AppendChild(artist);

// rinse...repeat...

// Finally add the new song to the SongsNode
SongsNode.AppendChild(newSong);
```

Comment: Thank you, i know what you mean. that's my puzzled on my code, because i make a new XmlDocument then, i don't know how to save it. could you help me one more question? how to delete the child "song" or add a "song"? such as bool DeleteSongByArtist(string sArtist); bool ChangeNodeInSong(string sArtist, string sNodeName, string value);

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to find a node and delete it, and how to add a new node.

Answer (score 0):

> please don't write a name of solution such as "Ling to xml"...acutally, i do many testes, but failed.

Still I think, this is a very good time to start to use Linq2Xml. If you don't like it, just ignore.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));

//Load Songs
var songs = xDoc.Descendants("Song")
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    Artist = s.Element("artist").Value,
                    Track = s.Element("track").Value,
                    Column = s.Element("column").Value,
                    Date = s.Element("date").Value,
                })
                .ToArray();

//Delete Songs
string songByArtist="mic";
xDoc.Descendants("Song")
    .Where(s => s.Element("artist").Value == songByArtist)
    .Remove();
string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

Comment: hehe. i don't want to complain...but the fact is...i worked many days, very little rest...my brain works bad for new things... if convenient, i will ask you more if learning "Ling".

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
        XmlNodeList SongList = doc.SelectNodes(@"//Songs/Song");
```

The // tells it to select the Songs node anywhere in document. This is better than

```
        doc.SelectNodes(@"/document/level1/music/Songs")
```

Note that the above statement is oviously not for your xml, but to prove a point about //
Using // removes the need for your docSub document and SongsNode element.
To add then delete a song, just use the following

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement ea = doc.SelectSingleNode("//songs");
        XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("song");
        XmlElement er;
        ea.AppendChild(el);
        //doing my work with ea
        //you could use innerxml.
        el.InnerXml = "<artist>Judas Priest</artist><track>7</track><column>good</column><date>1</date>";
        //or you can treat each node as above
        er = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        el.AppendChild(er);
        er.InnerText = "The Ripper";
        //but you don't nead this song any more?
        ea.RemoveChild(el);
        //so it's gone.
```

And thats all there is to it.